# jquery, keyup не работает на телефонах IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

keyup не работает на телефонах IOS, когда выбираю значение с выпадающего списка(приложил снизу фотографию)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код HTML

```
<input class="form-control " id="ccnum" type="text" name="ccnum"
                               placeholder="4542993192922293" list="creditcards_list"/>
                        <datalist id="creditcards_list"></datalist>
```

добавление options в datalist

```
        if (typeof cardData['card'] !== 'undefined') {
            if (cardData['card'].length > 0) {
                let str = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < cardData['card'].length; i++) {
                    str += '<option data-value="' + cardData['card'][i]['profileId'] + '" value="' + cardData['card'][i]['cardNumber'] + '" />'; // Storing options in variable
                }
                const creditcards_list = document.getElementById("creditcards_list");
                creditcards_list.innerHTML = str;
            }
        }
```

jquery keyup

```
jQuery('#ccnum').keyup(function () {
        const value = jQuery('#ccnum').val();
        const numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;

        if (value.substring(0, 4) == 'XXXX' && numberRegex.test(value.substring(5, 8)) === true && value.substr(8).length == 0) {
            jQuery('.card-block-info').hide();
            jQuery('.pay').show();
            jQuery('.next').hide();

        } else {
            jQuery('.card-block-info').show();
            jQuery('.pay').hide();
            jQuery('.next').show();
        }
    });
```

Как это исправить?
Также пробывал использовать (это не помогло)

```
 jQuery('#ccnum').on('keyup touchend' , function () {}
```

Comment: Если это элемент select, то пробуйте событие change. Если это элемент input, то событие input.

Comment: у меня datalist который привязан к input, обновил вопрос